# Store cron job schedule parameter in an entity

Tags: google-app-engine, cron, google-cloud-datastore, cron-task

I have this cron job in GAE

```
cron:
     - description: interactive
       url: /interactive
       schedule: every 1 minutes
```

everytime I want to change schedule to 5 minutes or 10 minutes, I have to open cron.yaml file, change the parameter and update the app. I think it is too annoying.

Is there anyway I can change the parameter without doing those steps. 
For example, store schedule parameter in an entity and update the entity. Is it possible?

Comment: No there isn't any way of doing this with cron.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to change these params is to update the `cron.yaml` and redeploy the app.

To make your life easier though you could enable the [push to deploy](https://developers.google.com/cloud/devtools/repo/push-to-deploy) for your app and edit this file (or any other file) either on GitHub or directly from [Google Console](https://console.developers.google.com/).

Comment: though you can just update cron and not the whole app.  `appcfg.py update_cron: Update application cron definitions.`